# Point cloud - Why don't all the points show up in AGOL or ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, las, point-cloud

Whenever I upload a LAS file in ArcGIS Pro, not all the points are shown. And there are even less points when I upload it to AGOL.

Is there a maximum of points ArcGIS Pro and AGOL can show ?

If yes, what can I do to make sure ALL the points are shown?

[image]

Comment: I think there is a limit number of points that you can upload to it in AGOL .  Is it small or larger area ?

Comment: can you share the LAS data and include some screenshots of what you are seeing. What do you see when you open the SLPK in Pro?

Answer (score -1):

Check the Map/Scene Properties > Extent and Clip layers options. Could be that the points are being hidden by one or both of these settings in Pro. For AGOL, i'm pretty sure you are limited to 2000 points only.

See: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/sharing/analyzer-error-messages/00221-feature-layer-is-displaying-more-than-2000-features.htm

Comment: Hi Sara, I checked what u said and No Clipping was set

Comment: The record count for 2000 records is for Feature Layers. This wouldn't be the case for scene layers which are cached..